# USB Wireless headset - Works in VMWare, not in host machine

Tags: windows-7, drivers, usb-2

Environment:
  Host - Win7 Pro SP1 64-bit
         VMWare Workstation 9.0.2

Guest - Win7 Pro SP1 64-bit

I have two devices on USB 2.0 ports: a wireless headset from Logitech (H800) and a scanner from HP (5590) that will not be recognized by the host system.  No matter how many times I install the scanner driver, it just won't work. The H800 keeps saying the driver is missing (and Logitech says the driver ships w/ Windows).  This is all with neither the guest operating system nor the VMWare environment running.

The devices do work on other machines.

However, when I run the guest operating system, and then connect the devices to it, they work just fine.  Because of that, I do not believe I have any cabling or power issues.

I suspect the problem lies in my system registry on the host machine, but I don't know enough about drivers to get any further than that.

Any insights?

Thanks.

Comment: When the devices refuse to be install is VMWare running the virtual machine at the time?  Have you made sure the device is disconnected from the guest operating system?  Have you tried these devices on another ssytem, its possible, the host operating system image is corrupt.

Comment: @Ramhound - good question.  I have edited my question to be more explicit about what was happening when.  Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: Are all the VMware services stopped?  Do the devices appear in Device Manager?  Make sure they aren't associated to a vmWare driver.

Comment: Come on, a downvote?  I've been working this problem on my own time for 2 weeks.  I came here for some advice.  Don't think I just dropped it on you because I couldn't use Google.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I hadn't thought of that, but after stopping all VMWare's UI, System Tray tools, and services, the results on the host are the same.  Thanks for the tip.  It was a good idea.

Comment: All - I never did figure this out.  I just used it as a good excuse to update to Windows 8.  I did a clean install, not an update.  All the hardware I've tried so far has worked fine.  Must have been a missing driver or bad registry entry somewhere.  Thanks for all the good ideas, though!